# meaning of double headed arrow

Tags: notation, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am studying properties of discrete time Fourier transform and I encountered a notation shown highlighted in attached photo
What is meant by this notation? Is it meaning equality?  [screenshot of notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncc6J.png)

Comment: I'd say it denotes a bijective correspondence.

Comment: $x(t) \leftrightarrow X(\omega)$ means that they are transform pair.